# Visual Studio 2012 designer error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-8

I am in the middle of Windows Store app development. Suddenly an exception occurred when I open XAML file
"**System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException.**
The application cannot be started. Try reinstalling the application to fix the problem. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80073CFC)"

What I tried so far:
1. Restart PC
2. Reinstall Visual Studio 2012 ultimate
3. Uninstall VS 2012 ultimate and installed VS2012 Express for windows 8.

but still the error is same.

The details of the error are:

`` Microsoft.Expression.HostUtility.AppPackage.AppPackageNativeMethods.IApplicationActivationManager.ActivateApplication(String appUserModelId, String activationContext, ActivateOptions options, Int32& processId)
   at Microsoft.Expression.HostUtility.AppPackage.WrtUtility.ActivateApplication(String appUserModelId, String activationContext, Object site)
   at Microsoft.Expression.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.ActivateApplicationInternal(String appUserModelId, String activationContext, Object site)
   at Microsoft.Expression.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateDesignerProcess(String applicationPath, String clientPort, Uri hostUri, IDictionary environmentVariables, Int32& processId, Object& processData)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.ProcessIsolationDomain..ctor(ProcessDomainFactory factory, IIsolationBoundary boundary, AppDomainSetup appDomainInfo, FrameworkName targetFramework, String identifier, String baseDirectory)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
   at Microsoft.Expression.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.CreateInstance[T](Type type)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolatedExportProvider.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExpressionHost.Services.VSIsolationService.CreateExportProvider(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, ICatalogFactory catalogFactory, IExportFilter filter)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IsolatedDesignerService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, CancellationToken cancelToken, DesignerServiceEntry& entry)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.InvokeWithCulture[T](CultureInfo culture, Func2 func, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.<>c__DisplayClassa1.b__6()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute() ``

Please help me.

Comment: That's ERROR_NEEDS_REMEDIATION.  Windows thinks that the app package has been tampered with.  Sounds like your machine is kinda messed up.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the app from your start menu? This looks like the sort of error you get when Visual Studio can't clear out your application's data for some reason. You might see if there is anything hanging around in %appdata%, too.

Comment: I have cleared Appdata for Visual Studio. But no difference.. Still error is same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same error occurred on my system. 
Even I 
1. Restarted machine several times
2. Uninstalled and Reinstalled VS 2012

But still I got the same error even in New project.

Since I had no other option left, I reinstalled Windows 8 after formatting my system.
 Not sure whether it was the best thing to do, but it worked for me.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to reinstal your windows you can just restore it and it will solve your problems. I used to have same problems and I solve it with system restore.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

Hi,

I faced the same issue caused by the developer license renewal process.  **You Dont need to reinstall your windows or even visual studio**. This is what fixed my problem.

1. Just goto PC Settings
2. Create a new User (windows user)
3. Logon to the new user account you made.
4. Start visual studio and open the solution you were working on.

try this before you go for reinstalling your windows.

Answer (score 0):

This following website might help your problem although the problem was on an older visual studio but I doubt it would fix the issue:
[here](http://lionsden.co.il/codeden/?p=488)

OR,try to put this inside the xaml file:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!-- 
                Styles that define common aspects of the platform look and feel
                Required by Visual Studio project and item templates
             -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Common/StandardStyles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <Style x:Key="BigGreenTextStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="36"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
            <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="WordEllipsis"/>
            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
            <Setter Property="Typography.StylisticSet20" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Typography.DiscretionaryLigatures" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Typography.CaseSensitiveForms" Value="True"/>
        </Style>
        <x:String x:Key="AppName">HelloWorld</x:String>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: 1. The website link you provided didn't help me to resolve the error.
2. I pasted the above xaml in new project's App.xaml file. But still no luck

I started believing what Hans Passant says - My system is messed up. Probably needs reinstalling Windows 8 and then VS 2012

Answer (score 0):

***how to resolve a problem of designer error..***

**1st ... set the path of temp tmp values as**

"C:\Windows.old\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Temp"

**2nd goto windows features ..**

and make perform this step which is in image ==..
[step 2 here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlHho.png)

**3rd goto  visual studio location and left click the icon.**

and make perform this step as well==.
 [step 3 here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlrIA.png**)