# Visual Studio 2012 designer crashes after developer license renewal

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps, designer

It has happened to be me twice. As soon as my developer license expires and it prompts me to renew it, my visual studio designer starts to crash and i get following exception when i try to load any xmal:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
The application cannot be started. Try reinstalling the application to fix the problem. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80073CFC)
   at Microsoft.Expression.HostUtility.AppPackage.AppPackageNativeMethods.IApplicationActivationManager.ActivateApplication(String appUserModelId, String activationContext, ActivateOptions options, Int32& processId)
   at Microsoft.Expression.HostUtility.AppPackage.WrtUtility.ActivateApplication(String appUserModelId, String activationContext, Object site)
   at Microsoft.Expression.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.ActivateApplicationInternal(String appUserModelId, String activationContext, Object site)
   at Microsoft.Expression.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateDesignerProcess(String applicationPath, String clientPort, Uri hostUri, IDictionary environmentVariables, Int32& processId, Object& processData)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.ProcessIsolationDomain..ctor(ProcessDomainFactory factory, IIsolationBoundary boundary, AppDomainSetup appDomainInfo, FrameworkName targetFramework, String identifier, String baseDirectory)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
   at Microsoft.Expression.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.CreateInstance[T](Type type)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolatedExportProvider.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExpressionHost.Services.VSIsolationService.CreateExportProvider(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, ICatalogFactory catalogFactory, IExportFilter filter)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IsolatedDesignerService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, CancellationToken cancelToken, DesignerServiceEntry& entry)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.InvokeWithCulture[T](CultureInfo culture, Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.<>c__DisplayClassa`1.<StartTask>b__6()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

I have tried a lot to find a solution to the problem but nothing worked the only way out was to re-install windows and re-install visual studio all over again.

Comment: It is a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633148/visual-studio-2012-designer-error).

Comment: formatting pc and re-install windows again ... ? I dont think its a batter way..

Comment: Try uninstalling the app, renaming the app package name, creating a new certificate in packaging tab and running the app again..

Comment: Similar: [Visual Studio 2013 (XAML?) Designer crash on all Windows Phone projects even after aquiring developer license](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25611523/1461424)

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing your visual studio and team foundation server (if applicable) cache. I know it sounds weird but my team all went through a very similar issue and this was the only thing that worked consistently (aside from a full re-install).

Delete all files in these locations:

TFS Cache: C:\Users[UserName]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation[Version]\Cache

One possible VS Cache Location: c:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\VWDCache

Connect issue that may or may not apply, just shows that VS loads cached versions of projects potentially with conflicting license information in your case: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/758523/visual-studio-2012-reloads-a-cached-version-of-an-edited-csproj-file

Answer (score 0):

Something similar happened to me once. Try cleaning the project, aka clean `bin` and `obj` folders from project folder.